Применяются не все стили к странице
Не пойму почему не все стили применяются к классу,также можете подсказать как сделать в  ссылки на разделы белым цветом,а в описании про себя сделать текст по центру-слева и кнопку как исправить.


* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside,
nav,
footer,
header,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.header {
  width: 1440px;
  height: 154px;
  background-color: rgba(7, 32, 63, 1);
  border: 0 0 1 0px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.start {
  width: 257px;
  height: 44px;
  border: 1px;
  background-color: ;
  text-decoration: ;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: px;
  margin-left: px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 55 55 135 1048px;
}

.end {
  width: 691px;
  height: 44px;
  gap: 40px;
  background-color: ;
  font-size: 36px;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 55 55 614 135px;
  text-decoration: ;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.about_me {
  height: 801px;
  width: 1440px;
  background-color: rgba(7, 32, 63, 1);
  color: orange;
  display: flex;
}

.info_1 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 78.02px;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
  width: 605px;
  height: 78px;
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-left: 137px;
  background-color: ;
}

.info_2 {
  width: 605px;
  height: 209px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
  margin-top: 49px;
  margin-left: 137px;
  background-color: red;
}

.button {
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 605px;
  height: 106px;
  background: rgba(217, 217, 217, 1);
  align-items: end;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 49px;
  margin-left: 137px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.avatar {
  width: 516px;
  height: 516px;
  margin-top: 135px;
  margin-left: 46px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 0 0 5 0 px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="start">
        @VLADOOS
      </div>
      <div class="end">
        <div class="end1"><a href="#">МОИ РАБОТЫ</a></div>
        <div class="end1"><a href="#">ОБО МНЕ</a></div>
        <div class="end1"><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="about_me">
        <div class="info">
          <div class="info_1">
            Я - фронтендер
          </div>
          <div class="info_2">
            Какая-то очень интересная информация обо мне. Очень интересная информация...
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button>связаться со мной</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="avatar">
          <img src="images/1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>





"Не пойму почему не все стили применяются к классу" -- о каком классе и стилях речь?

avatar. button, info_2, end

А что это за такой цвет background-color: ; и что это за такие величины размерности padding: 55 55 614 135px; что это за декорация такая text-decoration: ; бордеры border: 0 0 5 0 px;?

@Simon и margin с px, но без цифровых значений

бордеры border: 0 0 5 0 px; это свойство скопировал с figma,background-color: ; это использовал чтобы легче было опередлить местоположение фрагмента определенного класса,padding: 55 55 614 135px; отстыпы от страницы. Я только начинаю изучать frontend, поэтому могут быть костыли и ошибки в коде

@user24655331 это не валидный css, он не будет работать, ну и я не знаю, как Вам background-color без значения может помочь что-то понять
